# Prime number and Stone game. Who will win?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

2 players 'A' and 'B' are playing a game. A piles of Stone has n stones.Player can remove either one stone or stone equal to power of some prime number. The player who can not make a move in his turn loses.

'A' plays first. Both 'A' and 'B' play optimally, who will win the game?

I am new to such kind of problems, I tried making all possible situations, but i am unable to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Clearly A wins if $1\le n\le 5$, and B wins if $n=6$. Show that in general, if $n$ is not a multiple of $6$, then A can take stones so as to leave a multiple of $6$. Show further that if $n$ *is* a multiple of $6$, then A *cannot* move so as to leave a multiple of $6$.

Put these facts together properly, and you'll know exactly which $n$ are wins for A and which are wins for B, and also what the winning strategy is.

Answer (score 2):

This, like any impartial perfect information game, is Nim in disguise. You need to find the Nim-value of piles of $n$ stones. $1$ and any prime power are $*1$ because you can take all the stones and move to $0$. Then $6$ is $0$ as it loses. Look up the Sprague-Grundy theorem.